# Find the average number of coffees people drink-- almost correct(have some trouble with exception handling)

Tags: python-3.x

Write a program which reads names and the number of coffee cups from standard input to find:

the average number of coffees people drink

the number of people who drink less than the average number of coffees.

The program should prompt the user with Enter name and number of coffees: . Users can enter a name and integer number of coffee cups separated by a space character. The program will continue to ask the user for input until the user types stop

When the user enters stop, the program should print the average number of coffees everyone drinks to 2 decimal places, and the number of people who drink less than the average number of coffees.If no valid people were entered before the user types stop, simply print 'No one drinks coffee.'

Exception handling is required in the user input.The program should continue to prompt the user after they enter invalid input.The input must contain the name and number of coffee cups only, separated by a space character.

The cost (second element in the input) cannot be a negative number.

I want the program to print 'invalid input' after each input not after the 'stop' command is given. Can you help me modify the program to let it give results as expected ?

```
k=[]
names=[]
nums=[]
while True:
    n=input('Enter name and number of coffees: ')
    if n=='stop':
        break
    if n!='stop':
        k.append(n)
i=0
try:
    i=0
    while i<len(k):
        u=k[i].split()
        names.append(u[0])
        if int(u[1])>0:
            nums.append(int(u[1]))
        else:
            print('Invalid input. {} cannot drink negative cups of coffee.'.format(u[0]))
        i+=1
except ValueError:
    print('Invalid input. Number of coffees must be an integer.')
except IndexError:
    print('Invalid input. Requires name and number.')

try:
    average=sum(nums)/len(nums)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('No one drinks coffee.')
    exit()
k=0
count=0
while k<len(nums):
    nu=nums[k]
    if nu<average:
        count+=1
    k+=1
print('The average number of coffees is {:.2f}.'.format(average))
if count==0:
    print('0 people drink less than the average number of coffees.')
if count==1:
    print('{} person drinks less than the average number of coffees.'.format(count))
if count >1:
    print('{} people drink less than the average number of coffees.'.format(count))
```

Expected result 1:

```
Enter name and number of coffees: Daniel
Invalid input. Requires name and number.
Enter name and number of coffees: stop
No one drinks coffee.
```

Actual result 1:

```
Enter name and number of coffees: Daniel
Enter name and number of coffees: stop
Invalid input. Requires name and number.
No one drinks coffee.
```

Expected result 2:

```
Enter name and number of coffees: Gillian none
Invalid input. Number of coffees must be an integer.
Enter name and number of coffees: stop
No one drinks coffee.
```

Actual result 2:

```
Enter name and number of coffees: Gillian none
Enter name and number of coffees: stop
Invalid input. Number of coffees must be an integer.
No one drinks coffee.
```

Expected result 3:

```
Enter name and number of coffees: Adam -2
Invalid input. Adam cannot drink negative cups of coffee.
Enter name and number of coffees: stop
No one drinks coffee.
```

Actual result 3:

```
Enter name and number of coffees: Adam -2
Enter name and number of coffees: stop
Invalid input. Adam cannot drink negative cups of coffee.
No one drinks coffee.
```

Expected result 4:

```
Enter name and number of coffees: Adam -10
Invalid input. Adam cannot drink negative cups of coffee.
Enter name and number of coffees: Darcy
Invalid input. Requires name and number.
Enter name and number of coffees: Gillian $ten
Invalid input. Number of coffees must be an integer.
Enter name and number of coffees: stop
No one drinks coffee.
```

Actual result 4:

```
Enter name and number of coffees: Adam -10
Enter name and number of coffees: Darcy
Enter name and number of coffees: Gillian $ten
Enter name and number of coffees: stop
Invalid input. Adam cannot drink negative cups of coffee.
Invalid input. Requires name and number.
No one drinks coffee.
```

Actual(Expected) result 5:

```
Enter name and number of coffees: Susan 2
Enter name and number of coffees: Peter 3
Enter name and number of coffees: Harold 6
Enter name and number of coffees: stop
The average number of coffees is 3.67.
2 people drink less than the average number of coffees.
```

Comment: Hint: Your code grabs all the inputs before doing anything with any of them. If you need to give feedback after each line, you'll need to process each line as you receive it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the problem with your approach is that it does not process each input at the time it is given. You store everything in an array to process later. If you want results like your `expected output`'s, you need to do some processing each time you receive an input, inside your `while` loop. I've made some modifications to your code, check it out:

```py
names = []
nums = []

while True:
    n=input('Enter name and number of coffees: ')

    if n == 'stop':
        break

    try:
        name, number = n.split()
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid input. Requires name and number.')
    else:
        try:
            coffee_count = int(number)
            if coffee_count < 0:
                print('Invalid input. {} cannot drink negative cups of coffee.'.format(name))
            else:
                nums.append(coffee_count)
                names.append(name)
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid input. Number of coffees must be an integer.')

try:
    average=sum(nums)/len(nums)

    print('The average number of coffees is {:.2f}.'.format(average))
    below_average = sum([1 for num in nums if num < average])
    print('{} people drink less than the average number of coffees.'.format(below_average))
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('No one drinks coffee.')
```